# Facebook Connect Redirection Loop

Tags: facebook, cakephp

Hi all: 
When i try to use "Facebook Connect" to login on my website, i have the following problem:

If the application of my website is not added to facebook, i have to authorize it. Then I have a redirect loop in mozilla, chrome , but not in IE.
If the application is added to facebook, works ok.

does anybody know why?

Comment: huh?! application added to facebook?

Answer (score 1):

change your .htacces to default,  like :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|(.*)\.swf|assets|v1|images|flash|system|uploads|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

i guess you have set the incorrect url in fb for the redirect, make sure all the app settings are correct on fb and give it some time to propagate